pytorch CNN model parameters are not storing properly
The task at work is to make a CNN model to do some classification task on images. Also, I should be able to view the feature maps after making a classification on an image i.e. the images obtained after applying convolution or pooling operations. Below is how I defined my CNN class:
class ConvNet(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_channels, output_dim):
    super().__init__()
    # input 48x48
    self.architecture = {
        "conv1": self.convblock(input_channels, 128, (3,3)), # 46x46
        "conv2" : self.convblock(128, 64, (3, 3), bnorm=True), # 44x44
        "pool1" : self.poolblock((2,2)), # 22x22
        "conv3" : self.convblock(64, 16, (3,3), stride=2), #10x10
        "conv4" : self.convblock(16, 10, (3,3)), # 8x8
        "pool2" : self.poolblock((2,2), bnorm=10), # 4x4
        "feedforward" : nn.Sequential(
          nn.Flatten(), # 4x4x10 = 160
          nn.Linear(160, 128), # 128
          nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
          nn.Dropout(0.3),
          nn.Linear(128, output_dim), # 3
          nn.Softmax(dim=1)
        )                  
    }
    self.maps = {}

  def forward(self, x):
    image = x
    for name, layer in self.architecture.items():
      out = layer(image)
      self.maps[name] = out
      image = out
    return image
     
  def convblock(self, inp, out, kernel, stride=1, bnorm=False):
    if bnorm:
      return nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(inp, out, kernel, stride=stride),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(out)
      )
    else:
      return nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(inp, out, kernel, stride=stride),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
      )

  def poolblock(self, kernel, bnorm=None):
    if bnorm is None:
      return nn.MaxPool2d(kernel)
    else:
      return nn.Sequential(
          nn.MaxPool2d(kernel),
          nn.BatchNorm2d(bnorm)
      )

  def get_map(self, im, layer):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(20,10), gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [1,3]})
    ax[0].set_xticks([])
    ax[0].set_yticks([])
    ax[0].imshow(im.reshape(im.shape[-2],im.shape[-1],1), cmap="gray") # Shows Input image
    self(im)
    map = self.maps[layer]
    map=map.reshape(map.shape[1],1,map.shape[-2],map.shape[-1])
    ax[1].set_xticks([])
    ax[1].set_yticks([])
    rows = max(int(map.shape[0]/8), 8)
    ax[1].imshow(make_grid(map,nrow=rows).permute(1, 2, 0)) # Shows all the channels after an operation.

The idea is to store blocks of convolution and pooling layers in the self.architecture dictionary with names such as 'conv1', 'conv2', 'pool1' etc...
Then, in the forward method, I would run the input images through each block and also store the outputs of each block in the self.maps dictionary to retrieve later (self.get_map does this).
The problem is that the model's parameters are not being set properly. Below is the code where I instantiated the model and optimizer:
model = ConvNet(1, 3).to(device)
adam_opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

However I ran into the following error:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py in __init__(self, params, defaults)
    271         param_groups = list(params)
    272         if len(param_groups) == 0:
--> 273             raise ValueError("optimizer got an empty parameter list")
    274         if not isinstance(param_groups[0], dict):
    275             param_groups = [{'params': param_groups}]

ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list

I printed out the parameter list and it is empty. I don't understand why this is happening.
Is my way of defining the architecture or forward method wrong and PyTorch expects some specific behavior when subclassing nn.Module? If so what is it and how can I change my class? Any extra information on how Pytorch actually stores the class parameters is most welcomed.

The proper way to define a dictionary of layers in PyTorch is to wrap your dict with a nn.ModuleDict:
self.architecture = nn.ModuleDict({
    "conv1": self.convblock(input_channels, 128, (3,3)), # 46x46
    "conv2" : self.convblock(128, 64, (3, 3), bnorm=True), # 44x44
    "pool1" : self.poolblock((2,2)), # 22x22
    "conv3" : self.convblock(64, 16, (3,3), stride=2), #10x10
    "conv4" : self.convblock(16, 10, (3,3)), # 8x8
    "pool2" : self.poolblock((2,2), bnorm=10), # 4x4
    "feedforward" : nn.Sequential(
        nn.Flatten(), # 4x4x10 = 160
        nn.Linear(160, 128), # 128
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Dropout(0.3),
        nn.Linear(128, output_dim), # 3
        nn.Softmax(dim=1)
    )                  
})

You can test the parameters are registered by counting them:
>>> nn.utils.parameters_to_vector(net.parameters()).numel()
106897


Thanks @Ivan. That did solve the problem. From the docs: ModuleDict can be indexed like a regular Python dictionary, but modules it contains are properly registered, and will be visible by all Module methods. If possible can you tell me on what registered meant in this context?

When a module registers its child modules (submodules) they become accessible to the outside via nn.Module methods. Of course, you can still access those via standard Python attributes and keys, as you saw in your example, but it's just a dict, not a nn.Module, that is traversable and needed for recursive functions such as parameters to work.
